Column names auto conversion not done
The automatic mapping between entity attributes being in lowercase and table attributes being in snake case is not done thus throwing the following exception.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name : 'companyName'.

I'm using :

Microsoft SQL Server 2016
Spring Boot 2.1.8

I have a table TUSER with columns id, company_name.
I have an entity UserEntity :
@Entity
@Table(name = "TUSER")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String companyName;

    // getters and setters
}

What I've tried so far :

I've added the following properties in my application.properties file.

spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl


I put the property org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect in the entity manager factory :

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.domain.artifact.entity");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    
    return factory.getObject();
}



When I change the annotated column with @Column(name = "company_name"), it is working fine. Though I don't want to do this since the mapping from lower camel case to snake case should be done automatically.


I think the defaults already implements your "snake case" thing, so remove them settings

@siggemannen Removing the settings which try to implement the snake case conversion leads to the same issue.

then the issue is something else, perhaps you use some old version?

Implementing a custom SnakeCasePhysicalNamingStrategy solves the problem but I have no explanation why the default naming strategy is not applied.
